What lombok annotations are mandatory for a JPA entity
What lombok annotations are mandatory for a JPA entity, I am thinking of removing and @AllArgsConstructor. Should I remove @Data as well since I am overriding
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)

Do I need @Data?

@Data: This generates equals, hashCode, and toString methods, which can cause issues with JPA. It's better to avoid this annotation for entities and define these methods manually or use other Lombok annotations selectively.

Entity definition
@Slf4j
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
public class Foo extends Bar {
..
}


I didn't understand the question. Don't you want to use Lombok?

Actually, it's just the other way around: Only use those Lombok annotations that you actually need and also know what they do. Basically, you do not need ANY lombok annotation for a JPA Entity (except the @Entity annotation, which is actually JPA itself: javax.persistence.).

@AnishB. just need to know what annotations are needed for my Entity class if I use inheritance

Got it. Thanks.

I believe that the Lombok annotations are not mandatory for JPA entities. In fact, you should use them wisely.
Using @Data or @EqualsAndHashCode for JPA entities is not recommended. It can cause severe performance and
memory consumption issues, such as:

Accidentally loading lazy attributes
Broken HashSets and HashMaps
Missing No-Argument constructor

You can find here what to do instead.
@ToString can still be used, but all the lazy fields need to be excluded. This can be achieved by placing @ToString.Exclude on the desired fields, or by using @ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true) on the class and @ToString.Include on non-lazy fields.
I personally use @Getter, @Setter, and @Accessors annotation
in my JPA entities. I keep the no-arguments constructor (no need to use Lombok for that), which is mandatory for JPA entities.
In addition to fluent setters (generated with Lombok), to build a new instance:
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = false)
@Entity
@Table(name = "foos")
public class Foo extends Bar {
    private Strig name;
    private String description;
}

var foo = new Foo().setName("Foo").setDescription("fu fu");


You don't need any Lombok annotations for JPA entities.
If you add @AllArgsConstructor you will need @NoArgsConstructor as well, so there is a default constructor.
You shouldn't override @Data either add your own or let it use the JVM default

I don't use @AllArgsConstructor at all, not so useful if you have more columns in JPA entity
